# Dynamic score within range based on value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am attempting to score a record based on where it's value falls within a range. I know I can create a lookup table but that would be rather time intensive and was hoping for additional options.

Example:
Lower bound of 0
Upper bound of 90

Record has a score of 67

What I want to do is score that record between 1 - 3 based on where the value of 67 falls within the range of 10 - 90. So in this instance this record would score a 2.25, or the like.

Thank you in advance for your assistnace!

Comment: How granula do you want your scores?  In increments of 0.25?

Comment: *"Lower bound of 0 Upper bound of 90"* ... *"falls within the range of 10 - 90"*. Specifics please, we can't help you if you don't tell us what you're trying to accomplish or if you contradict yourself.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple linear equation

With 67 in **A1**, in **A2** enter:

```
=A1*0.025+1
```

and then apply rounding.

The 0.025 comes from `=(3-1)/(90-10)`

[image]

The above chart shows the mapping of records between 10 and 90 into scores between 1 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the score is linear, the following formula should work

```
=Record/(UpperRange - Lower Range)*2+1
```

In the example you give, this would be: `67/(90-10)*2+1` and the result would be 2.675

Answer (score 0):

If you want the scores to go from 1 to 3, in 0.25 increments, with a lower bound of 0, and upper of 90, then:

```
=ROUNDDOWN(SCORE/(90/8),0)*0.25+1
```

Which gives 2.25